# Can mod_rewrite ignore custom filename prefix?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

For search engine optimisation purpose I would like to make uploaded images more search engine friendly. Currently, all uploaded images are stored in subfolders based on account_id filename is MD5 of image_id so final path is looking like this:

```
/media/[range]/[account_id]/[size]/[hash].jpg
```

which is transformed to something like this:

```
/media/2000/1127/preview/ebb71045453f38676c40deb9864f811d.jpg
```

I would like custom prefix to filename so it could look like this:

```
/media/.../my-custom-image-description.ebb71045453f38676c40deb9864f811d.jpg
```

Is it possible to strip this custom description from filename using mod_rewrite rule, if yes how this rule should look like?

**UPDATE**

technically I have to subtract filename length to 36 characters to make it work so url like this:

```
/media/2000/1127/preview/nice-image-description.ebb71045453f38676c40deb9864f811d.jpg
```

would get translated to this:

```
/media/2000/1127/preview/ebb71045453f38676c40deb9864f811d.jpg
```

Comment: @derobert: I disagree: this is not administration, this is programming. `mod_rewrite` may not be Turing-complete, but it is a form of programming. (also, as of now, there are 2,764 questions here tagged `mod-rewrite`)

Comment: @Piskvor: mod_rewrite is actually turing complete :D

Comment: @olsner: I can't decide if that's awesome or horrible ;) Thanks for the information, I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Put that into your `.htaccess`:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule .*\.([a-f0-9]+)\.jpg $1.jpg
```

Should work properly ;-).

Comment: I'm assured that it works... I tried it on my server ;-). Maybe you copied it into the wrong dir. Do you receive an error? // **matches**: this-is-a-wonderful-description.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.jpg --> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.jpg ...

Comment: could be, I have placed .htaccess inside media folder, as I have different settings for parent directory.